# How to save list of items into database when we have UUID in spring boot jpa

Tags: spring, jpa, uuid

We have a requirement where 3k to 4k records we need to save into database. User will add multiple items or select all to add to his watchlist after applying filter. I tried savellAndFlush(list) this is taking list of objects but while saving only one record is getting saved into database.

We are using Spring boot and JPA repository
Domain:

```
@Id    
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")   
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")    
@Column(name = "PK_WISHLIST_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 30, scale = 0)    
private String pkWishListId;

List<WatchList> watchList = new ArrayList<WatchList>();

watchListRepo.saveAllAndFlush(watchList);
```

This is executing without any issues but in database its not inserting all records, instead inserting only one record.

Comment: And you are sure you have more than one record in the list?

Comment: yes we have 2k records in list while debugging i can see data. no error is there in console as well. when i check in database only one record is getting inserted.

Comment: Did you override the equals method of WatchList?